# Someone (trying to) delete images?

Tags: discussion

I've just run through the "Suggested edits" queue, and noticed that two of the edits were to remove useful images of actual documents.  Unfortunately I'd rejected both edits before I noticed the trend.

Is this vandalism, or a misguided attempt to clean up unnecessary images?

One of the questions was:

[Can anyone tell if an EU driving licence has been exchanged from a non-EU country?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15530/can-anyone-tell-if-an-eu-driving-licence-has-been-exchanged-from-a-non-eu-countr)

Comment: Review links: [1](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12296), [2](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12311). Based on the username, both were suggested by the OP who lost access to their original account.

Comment: @AndrewT. That's odd.  Different OP's, at the same time.  I'm still suspicious.  A vandal could create socks with the same user name too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one of the examples, the picture (if you zoom in) was actually showing some data which might be PII - so I accepted the edit and also asked for it to be scrubbed. The edit was also a rollback by the original user - probably that's why it ended up in the review queue.

For the other link, the username matches though they are different accounts - but everything points to the fact that they are actually the same user. The picture doesn't seem to contain any PII however so I think it should be kept.